# Limiting the number of JSON objects to process

Tags: php, arrays, object, json

```
<?php
// JSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://api.feedbin.me/v2/entries.json';

$username = 'username';  // authentication
$password = 'password';  // authentication

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password   // authentication
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting JSON result string

    $i=0;
    foreach (json_decode($result) as $obj) {
    if($i==5) break;
        $feedbin_title = $obj->title;
        $feedbin_url = $obj->url;
        echo '<li><a href="', $feedbin_url, '">', $feedbin_title, '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

I get a 100 objects JSON result. I'm trying to limit the objects processed to the first 5.
Why doesn't work the `$i=0; if($i==5) break;` thing? :)

Comment: You forget to increment `$i` itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neater solution would be to use:

`foreach (array_slice(json_decode($result), 0, 5) as $obj) {`

It'll save you creating a variable just to count :)

Comment: And it garbage collects the extra elements of the result sooner, too. :)

Comment: @Barmar But it is slower. As array_slice is a very high cost operation. If you access an array of 1000000 elements or 5 elements at index 4, it has the same run time.

Comment: @bwoebi Are you confusing `array_slice` with `array_splice`? The latter has to update the original array, the former doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar (I had fixed my typo in my comment) The first has to duplicate the variables, while the latter has not to. Also creating arrays is not fast.

Comment: @Barmar It's not always: shorter it is, better it is.

Comment: This solution is interesting! So, is array_slice slower and a high cost for the CPU or I can safely use it? :)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno It's slower, but not so slow that you'd really notice the little decrease in performance. About a tenth of a millisecond. But don't use it if you loop over it in a loop of 1000 iterations for example.

Comment: And regarding the cost on the CPU?

Comment: In your case, it's going to be insignificant, you won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increment `$i`. Now it runs through the whole array, checking every time if `$i`, which is always 0, is equal to five.

Write instead:

```
if($i++ == 5) break;
```

which counts up until `$i` is 5.

Comment: I'm getting the first 4 with this :o

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno fixed (This only returns 5 if you'd put it at the bottom of your loop...)

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the `$i` value, try adding `$i++` in your `foreach()` loop... try `foreach(json_decode($result) as $i => $obj)`